# main() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, program-entry-point

I have seen a `main()` function in some JavaScript files I have come across. Is it the same main function as you use in other languages such as C#, C++?? If you put a main function in your JS file, is that where the code starts executing? Or is it just another name used for a function?

I have searched the web but didn't find anything useful regarding this matter.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses :)

Comment: if those JS files contain webGL code its pretty possible that the `main()` function you saw belongs to that.

Comment: @jAndy no, it didn't have anything to do with webGL

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, `main` is not the same in JavaScript as in C languages. It's just another function, but the original programmer is probably using the name as a convention to indicate where the code *should* start running.

Comment: main file itself is main function in JS

Comment: suppose you have `index.js` and it is the entry point then the index.js file is the main

Answer (score 9):

"Main" function has nothing different then any other function (Its just a name). It will run when called and not automatically.

Answer (score 5):

It is just a name given to a function, there isn't such a thing as C "main" in javascript.